# Dealing with widows in a multicol environment

Tags: latex, multicol

I have problems with dealing with widows within a multicols environment, that is, I have not managed to instruct LaTeX to remove the them.

[This PDF document](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/328685/multicol-widows.pdf) shows an example of the problem. At the top of the second page, I get a widow from the last paragraph of the first page. I have tried a couple of approaches, without luck:

- setting both `\widowpenalty` and `\clubpenalty` to high values
- switching between `\raggedcolumns` and `\flushcolumns`
- adjusting the `collectmore` and `unbalance` counters

I've also read through the [documentation for multicol](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf) but have not found anything useful.

Is there anything else I could try?

([The complete LaTeX document for the above example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/328685/multicol-widows.tex))

Comment: Very good question and very interesting problem.

Comment: this doesn't exactly solve your problem, but have you thought about trying to adjust the space between your columns?

Comment: Mica: Have not tried that. Not sure it would look good though, as the document includes many two col multicols environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{\obeyspaces\gdef\nomorebreak{\beginnomorebreak\let \nobreakspace}}
\def\beginnomorebreak{\begingroup
   \def\par{\endgraf\endgroup\par\penalty 9999 }\obeyspaces
   \brokenpenalty 10000 \widowpenalty 10000 \clubpenalty 10000 }
\def\nobreakspace{\vadjust{\nobreak} \removespaces}
\def\removespaces{\futurelet\next\checkspace}
\def\checkspace{\ifx\next\nobreakspace\expandafter\removesinglespace\fi}
\def\removesinglespace#1{\removespaces}
```

Insert `\nomorebreak` at any place of your paragraph. Page breaks will be prohibited after this macro until the end of the paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the TeX FAQ item [Controlling widows and orphans](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-widows) has some options you did not try yet.

> Getting rid of a widow can be more tricky. Options are
>
> - If the previous page contains a long paragraph with a short last line, it may be possible to set it “tight”: write `\looseness=-1`
>     immediately after the last word of the paragraph.
> - If that doesn’t work, adjusting the page size, using `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` to “add a line” to the page, which
>     may have the effect of getting the whole paragraph on one page.
> - Reducing the size of the page by `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}` may produce a (more-or-less) acceptable “two-line widow”.